# Sudzc passing parameter at data type NSMutableArray

Tags: web-services, soap, xcode4, sudzc

I'm doing iPhone app i use webservice generated by sudzc but i don't understand parameter NSMutableArray that must return

> [service GetShopByService:self
>   action:@selector(GetShopByServiceHandler:) ItemID:[NSMutableArray
>   array]];

i have to do.
ItemID:[NSMutableArray array]

help me please;

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the array in the parameter field..

> [service GetShopByService:self
>   action:@selector(GetShopByServiceHandler:) ItemID:**myarray**];

**myarray** is a NSMutablearray in which you will add/store the values that you need to send. For getting specific response.